# Which Chinese food was accidentally invented by The Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

I remember a scene of 11th Doctor (Matt Smith) calling or writing to Amy saying what he did last week. He told something like he accidentally invented pasta or noodle or something. Which food was it? Google didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the minisode ["Pond Life" Part 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxXAY7LyjcM).

The Doctor is pretty non-specific. All he says is:

> **Doctor:** Also, I think I may have accidentally invented pasta.
>
> <sup><sub>[Full minisode transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/33-05.htm), with thanks to rand al'thor for the find</sub></sup>

It's hard to tell what *kind* of pasta, but based on the brief glimpse, it appears to be a wide spaghetti. Then again it also looks like the Doctor's "friend" is eating it raw, so who knows?

Comment: Transcript available [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/33-05.htm).

Comment: @randal'thor Thanks for the link! Added it to the answer

Comment: he accidentally invented pasta, not a pasta, pasta, the concept of pasta :-P